# Problem with xticks when importing Matlab figures using matlab2tikz

Tags: pgfplots, matlab, matlab2tikz

When importing the following figure 
[image]

using the **Matlab2Tikz**, I obtain the following output [image] , with the xticks strangely exported . Does any one have an idea how I can prevent this? Maybe by passing an extra inut to the matlab2tikz function?

Hier is a simple Matlab Code :

```
close all
x=linspace(5*10^-2,10*10^-2);
y1=-4*10^5*x+2;
y2=-4*10^5*x+1;
figure;
    subplot(121);plot(x,y1);xlabel('x');ylabel('y')
    subplot(122);plot(x,y2);xlabel('x');ylabel('y')
matlab2tikz('Test.tikz','standalone', true,'extraAxisOptions','label style={font=\Large}')
```

The obtained *.Tikz  file without the data:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=1.95217803030303in,
height=3.565625in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.04,
xmax=0.1,
xlabel={x},
ymin=-40000,
ymax=-15000,
ylabel={y},
name=plot1,
label style={font=\Large}
]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example (MWE) of the Matlab code you're using to generate the Matlab figure, as well as the matlab2tikz command? This might make it easier for us to identify the problem.

Comment: Why is it strange that the `xlabel`s are exported from MATLAB? Is this not expected? I think the simplest solution would be to refrain from setting `xlabel` in MATLAB. Or call `matlab2tikz` before adding the `xlabel`s, if they are required for your visualization in MATLAB.

Comment: I think what the question actually means is `xtick` and not `xlabel`.

Comment: @Ali, if that's the case, `xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed}` should be added to the value of `matlab2tikz`'s `'extraAxisOptions'` key.

Comment: @PaulGessler Sorry, as Ali said, I meant the xticks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scale your ticks to get rid of powers of 10 and get a more elegant look on your axes. Alternatively, as Paul Gessler suggested, you can also use fixed formatting with desired precision. The example below gives you the idea.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  width=2in,
  height=3in,
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$x^2$},
  ylabel near ticks,
  every axis label/.style={font=\small},
  scaled x ticks=base 10:2,
  scaled y ticks=base 10:-3,
  every tick label/.style={font=\footnotesize},
  tick scale binop=\times,
  title={With scaled x ticks},
  title style={above=1.5ex},
]
\addplot [color=black,solid,mark=o,domain=0.04:0.1,samples=10] {-4*10^5*x+1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  width=2in,
  height=3in,
  xlabel={$x$},
  xticklabel style={
    /pgf/number format/precision=2,
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
  },
  ylabel={$x^2$},
  ylabel near ticks,
  every axis label/.style={font=\small},
  every tick label/.style={font=\footnotesize},
  tick scale binop=\times,
  title={With fixed x ticks},
  title style={above=1.5ex},
]
\addplot [color=black,solid,mark=o,domain=0.04:0.1,samples=10] {-4*10^5*x+1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but this problem is occuring so many times, and how can I force pgflatex to take the same xticks from Matlab?